# Añadir "link rel" con emmet en json, html

Tags: html, vscode, emmet

Yo cada vez que escribo "html:5" y pulso enter se genera esto:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Desde la configuración de vscode en json puse lo siguiente para que en "html lang" no esté "en" y esté "es".

```
"emmet.variables": {
"lang": "es"
```

},

Mi pregunta es: cómo puedo hacer en json para que al escribir "html:5" o "!" me genere lo siguiente:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="" type="" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="" type="" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

O sea, que me añada 2 link rel en el head.
Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Podrías simplemente copiar y pegar una línea de un link rel..

Comment: No se mucho de como tu ide procesa el json. Pero no puedes colocar:"link":{"rel":""}